# Taking an array as a parameter and returning average

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get get the min, max, and average values of an array. I was able to successfully get the min and max values, but average function is giving me troubles.

Can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the code.

```
package basics;

public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String []args) {



        int[] numbers;
        numbers=new int[]{24,29,17, 46, 44, 35, 37, 13, 1}; 

        int max=getMax(numbers);
        System.out.println(max);

        int min=getMin(numbers);
        System.out.println(min);

        int avg=getAverage(numbers);
        System.out.println(average);

        }


    public static int getMax(int[] inputArray){ 
            int maxValue = inputArray[0]; 
            for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){ 
              if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 
                 maxValue = inputArray[i]; 
              } 
            } 
            return maxValue; 
          }

    public static int getMin(int[] inputArray){ 
            int minValue = inputArray[0]; 
            for(int i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){ 
              if(inputArray[i] < minValue){ 
                minValue = inputArray[i]; 
              } 
            } 
            return minValue; 

    public static int getAverage(int[] inputArray) {
            int getAverage = inputArray[0]; 
            int sum=0;
            for (i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                    sum = sum + inputArray[i];
               }
                return sum / inputArray.length;
            }

      }     

 }
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include the expected vs actual behavior?

Comment: That being said, what is so special about the first element of your array that you don't include it in the average?

Comment: @azurefrog I once made that small mistake and spent forever debugging it ;)

Comment: Remove this int getAverage = inputArray[0];  and start you for loop with i=0

Answer (score 2):

You aren't adding the first term of `inputArray` to the variable `sum`. Also, return type must be double to get decimal values.

You can try changing `sum` type to double and, since you are not using `getAverage` variable, remove it and make the loop iterate over all terms in `inputArray`.